# ¿Cómo unir la interfaz gráfica con una BD xampp en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

me han mandado a hacer un trabajo que requiere de una interfaz gráfica para ingresar datos que deben interactuar con una BD de datos, logré hacer que los botones me redirigieran a las ventanas correspondientes y realicé la conexión a xampp pero no sé como hacer que la interfaz gráfica agregue datos a la BD y que los botones de la interfaz también puedan interferir en la BD por ejemplo un botón buscar que me permita obtener un dato específico en la BD o  que en la ventana de agregado de datos los datos se actualicen en la BD. Tambien, ¿cómo podría hacer para que los datos que yo añada se guarden correctamente en la ficha de listar?[image: Agregar][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[][4]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Xamp no es una base de datos. y todo lo que pedis hay que programarlo en tu programa. De eso investigaste algo?

Comment: Si he estado investigando, xampp no es una base de datos, pero me permite realizar una conexión a una a través de Java, puede realizar todo bien hasta allí, pero ahora no entiendo como unir la conexión a la interfaz gráfica generada haciendo que dicha interfaz pueda interactuar con mi conexión.

Comment: No. Xamp es una virtualizacion de un sistema que contiene una base de datos. De igual manera podrias instalar tu base de datos en tu pc y seria exactamente lo mismo. Tambien podrias instalar cualquier base de datos y seria lo mismo. Aparte de ello, con Java (o c#, o python, o php o una lista interminable de lenguajes), podes conectarte a una base de datos (cualquiera). Lo que tenes que buscar, son tutoriales respecto a como conectarte por **codigo** desde java a tu base de datos (que implica conocimiento de objetos y clases y otras cosas). La pregunta asi como esta aca, es muy amplia

Answer (score 0):

Como sabrás, la unión de "interfaz gráfica" y base de datos, no existe. Lo que si existe es la carga de datos desde la interfaz gráfica de tu app, hacia la base de datos. Dicho esto, responderé tu pregunta a detalle.

Paso 01.- Crear una clase en un Package nuevo llamado "Conexion" (o como gustes, es solo para diferenciar). Te recomiendo hacer esto, porque es ULTRA NECESARIO para llamar al método de conexión en cada una de tus vistas o interfaces.

Algo similar a esto:

```
public class ConexionMysql {
public Connection con=null;
public String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
public String usuario = "root";
public String clave = "";


public ConexionMysql(String nombre){
    URL += nombre+"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
}

public Connection getConnection(){       
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL,
                usuario,clave);
        System.out.println("Conexion estabalecida correctamente.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConexionMysql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    return con;
}
```

}

Paso 02.- Sobre la vista que estás trabajando, importa la conexión y empieza a ejecutar sentencias SQL con los valores que recibas de tu formulario

Ejemplo:

```
try{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String idUsuario =  request.getParameter("idUsuario");
        String ciudad =  request.getParameter("ciudad");
        String comuna =  request.getParameter("comuna");
        String direccion =  request.getParameter("direccion");
        String numero =  request.getParameter("numero");
        String dormitorios =  request.getParameter("dormitorios");

        String banios =  request.getParameter("banios");
        String m2 =  request.getParameter("m2");
        String uf =  request.getParameter("uf");
        ConexionMysql conn = new ConexionMysql("MIBD");
        Connection conex = conn.getConnection();

        String SQL = "insert into departamentos (ciudad,comuna,direccion,numero,dormitorios,banios,m2,estado,uf,Usuarios_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'no verificado',?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conex.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.setString(1,ciudad);
        ps.setString(2,comuna);
        ps.setString(3,direccion);
        ps.setString(4,numero);
        ps.setString(5,dormitorios);
        ps.setString(6,banios);
        ps.setString(7,m2);
        ps.setString(8,uf);
        ps.setString(9,idUsuario);
        int resultado = ps.executeUpdate();
```